# Как скопировать все дерево переменной из DOM

Tags: firebug, dom

Приветствую!
Господа, подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли в firebud во вкладке DOM сохранить в файл полную структуру содержимого какой-то переменной? Со все подструктурой. А то у меня 35000 элементов, каждый нужно раскрать а потом скопировать. Либо просто раскрыть сразу все дерево с подразделами чтоб можно было скопипастить, а то в свернутьм виде оно дает текст вида ААААА ......... ББББББ
Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: попробуйте выбрать нужную ноду и нажать `*`.

Comment: Странно, но у меня ничего не вышло, лишь если я просто нажимаю стрелочку вправо то раскрывается один главный плюсик. Может я сделал что-то не так?